# Is there a way to create a print preview dialog with a fix layout?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, printing

I have a data for employees, and I wanted to print employee's profile. I wanted to print 4 copies of employee profile at time, in one bond paper only to save resources, you know.

My desired flow go's like this; I'll search for an employee, click a button "Save for printing" and the employee's profile will be save on the "Copy 1" for printing and so on with the others till the four (4) copies get filled.

[image]

Comment: The entire page is your canvas, you just need to loop through your four items and set the coordinates in the page for where your stuff should print.  Try it.

Comment: That was exactly what am thinking atm. But... but.. but... am new in this stuff, dunnu how to do it technically.

Comment: This website typically expects you to do some research and show your coded attempt.  We can help with that.  Right now, your question is just asking us to do the code for you.

Comment: my "technically" does not mean "do the code for me", what I mean there is somewhat like a flow.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but in either case, you have to show the code that you tried.